# Table build with $.each and AJAX contains only th and no td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

In my result, I only see the `th`, but the `td` are not rendered at all.
I have no problem with my data. I think I built my table incorrectly.

```
var table_html = '<table>';
table_html += '<thead>'
table_html += '<th>No</th>'
table_html += '<th>Name</th>'
table_html += '</thead>'

table_html += '<tbody>'

$.ajax({
    url:'/reports/name-report',
    type:'POST',
    data: options,
    success:function(result){
        console.log(result.details);

        $.each(result.details, function(i,obj){
            i = i + 1;
            table_html += '<tr>'
            table_html += '<td>'+i+'</td>'
            table_html += '<td>'+obj.name+'</td>'
            table_html += '</tr>'
        })

    },
    error:function(err){

    }
});

table_html += '</tbody>'
table_html += '</table>'
$("#myModal .modal-body").empty().append(table_html);
```

Comment: Move `table_html += '</tbody>'
table_html += '</table>'
$("#myModal .modal-body").empty().append(table_html);` at the end of `success` callback.

Comment: The `$.ajax` method is asynchronous - please all the `table_html` references *inside* the `success` handler function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $.ajax method is asynchronous  so you can try like

```
var table_html = '<table>';
table_html += '<thead>'
table_html += '<th>No</th>'
table_html += '<th>Name</th>'
table_html += '</thead>'

table_html += '<tbody>'

$.ajax({
    url:'/reports/name-report',
    type:'POST',
    data: options,
    success:function(result){
        $.each(result.details, function(i,obj){
            i = i + 1;
            table_html += '<tr>'
            table_html += '<td>'+i+'</td>'
            table_html += '<td>'+obj.name+'</td>'
            table_html += '</tr>'
        })
        table_html += '</tbody></table>'
        $("#myModal .modal-body").empty().append(table_html);
    },
    error:function(err){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the code in the `success` callback is only executed once you have received the AJAX response. So the order of execution is like this:

- The first half of the table (`<table>` to `<tbody>`) is added to `table_html`.
- The AJAX call is initiated.
- The second half of the table (`</tbody>`to `</table>`) is added to `table_html`.
- The content of `table_html`, *without the middle part with the data* that has not yet been added since the `success` callback has not yet been executed, is appended to your modal.
- The `success` callback is executed once the AJAX call gets a response. It adds the middle parts of the table (all the `<tr>`) to the end of the variable, but it makes no difference since the table has already been appended.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) post gives a good general explanation of the problem.

In your case, you can solve the problem like this:

```
//Append an empty table.
var table_html = '<table id="my_table">';
table_html += '<thead>'
table_html += '<th>No</th>'
table_html += '<th>Name</th>'
table_html += '</thead>'
table_html += '<tbody>'
//This row will show a loading message.
//It will be removed once the actual content has loaded.
table_html += '<tr><td colspan=2>Loading content...</td></tr>'
table_html += '</tbody>'
table_html += '</table>'
$("#myModal .modal-body").html(table_html);

//Do the AJAX call.
$.ajax({
    url:'/reports/name-report',
    type:'POST',
    data: options,
    success:function(result){
        //This code will only run when you get the AJAX response.
        //Create the inner part of the table.
        var tr_html = "";
        $.each(result.details, function(i,obj){
            i = i + 1;
            tr_html += '<tr>'
            tr_html += '<td>'+i+'</td>'
            tr_html += '<td>'+obj.name+'</td>'
            tr_html += '</tr>'
        })
        //Append the inner part to the table.
        //This will overwrite the tr with the loading message we added earlier.
        $("#my_table tbody").html(tr_html);
    }
});
```

*Disclaimar:* I have not tested this code.